# Docker container script returned exit code 143 while container is still running

Tags: docker, exit-code, sigterm

I run into a situation when Jenkins deployment broke with

```
+ docker run --name planning_31_deploy_prod --rm fd1c9016 sh -c 'npx sls config credentials --stage prod --provider aws --profile prod --key **** --secret **** && npx sls deploy --force --stage prod --region us-west-2 --aws-profile prod'
Sending interrupt signal to process
Serverless: Setting up AWS...
...
script returned exit code 143
```

While container is still running on an Instance - I can see that by `docker ps` and `docker container logs -f [id]`. What could be the reason of SIGTERM (Exit Code 143)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exit Code 143 indicates that the container successfully gracefully terminated after receiving the operating system's SIGTERM signal, which instructs the container to do so (otherwise you will see Exit Code 137).

In your case, I believe the AWS script you are trying to run contains an exit 143 statement. I don't know exactly what is causing the exit from the code but I found a sample code from AWS as you can see in the below screenshot.

My suggestion is to check:

- your configuration
- the network
- the secrets

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have added `--verbose` argument to `npx sls deploy` command for debugging. Waiting for the output